# Lookahead with postfix language

Tags: c++, parsing

Let's say I have a postfix language like

```
3 2 result +      // equivalent to result = 3 + 2
result 1 result + // equivalent to ++result
```

how should I implement a lookahead for a recursive descent parser (I'm doing this in C++)?

I'm unsure on how to design such a parsing algorithm since I can't deduce the type of instruction from just the first token

Comment: Whether you want to parse this language, or just evaluate its semantics, it's probably best to learn about [stack-oriented programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language). Put simply, you'd loop through reading a token, deciding how many elements to pop from the stack (zero or more), "execute" the meaning of the token, and push elements to the stack (zero or more). Both a parser and an interpreter could be built by assigning the appropriate meaning to tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you don't really need any lookahead at all, just the current token.

Push the current token on to a stack, and when you reach end of the line (which could be its own token) then you look at the top of the stack to see what the operation is (and of course pop it from the stack). Then pop the number of operands needed by the operation. If there are more entries on the stack after this you, or if there's not enough operands, then you have an error.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose C++ doesn't work this way right? I don't think the ; line terminator is used to pop arguments off of a stack when reached

Comment: @Dean No, C++ definitely doesn't work like that. :) In fact, C++ is notoriously hard to parse correctly (just look at [the most vexing parse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) for an example).